# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `filename' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am using rails Active storage to add attachments to my assignments model and it keeps throwing the above error

I had earlier used carrierwave gem but decided to use Active Storage instead. I need the views to show a file and a name but the error keeps showing.
When I comment out that line, the assignment views are working but cannot as images even if the files is a word or pdf or excel document.

```
  <% if @assignment.attachments.attached? %>
   <p>
    <strong>Attachments</strong><br>
    <% @assignment.attachments.each do |attachment| %>
    <%= image_tag url_for(@assignment.attachment) %>
    <%= link_to rails_blob_path(@assignment.attachment.filename, 
    disposition: "attachment") %>

  <% end %>
   </p>
```

The model for assignments

```
    class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
     has_many_attached :attachments
    end
```

In the controller for assignments I have allowed attachments in params as follows

```
       attachments: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `.each` loop, each of the attachment entries will be known as `attachment` and not as `@assignment.attachment`. In the case of the error, `@assignment.attachment` is nil.

Update your code to have the following two lines:

`<%= image_tag url_for(attachment) %>
<%= link_to rails_blob_path(attachment.filename, disposition: "attachment") %>`

Comment: When I update the code as per Dave Satchell, it throws the error undefined method `signed_id' for #<ActiveStorage::Filename:0x007f76f46f4330>

Comment: This is an ActiveStorage issue with direct uploads - take a look at the issue here https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32365

Comment: If you are just testing while you are writing code and have nothing useful in the database, you can try clearing it, otherwise check some of the other solutions